# What does 石ころネタ mean?

Tags: meaning

> : 昔{むかし}　脚本{きゃくほん}にダメ出{だ}ししようとして「いきなり現場{げんば}に来るとは何事{なにごと}か帰れ二度と来るな」って怒鳴{どな}られた原作{げんさく}の話とか聞きたい？
>
> : なにその業界石{ぎょうかいいし}ころネタ!?

I don't get what 石ころネタ means in this sentence. I've found an entry for a meaning of 石ころ in a [thesaurus](http://thesaurus.weblio.jp/content/%E7%9F%B3%E3%81%93%E3%82%8D) for 誰からも気にかけられることがない、無価値{むかち}であるさま but it doesn't seem to match up to the context.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

石ころネタ is quite a new word, probably slang, to mean ありふれた話, どこにでもある話, "a common, just an ordinary story", "the same old story". I think 業界石ころネタ is like 業界のありふれた話, "a common story/anecdote in the world of show business".

We commonly say 「そんなもの、そこらへんにごろごろあるよ / ごろごろしてるよ / ごろごろ転がってるよ」 to mean something is quite common and can be found everywhere, and often use expressions like 「どこにでも転がっている話」「そこらへんにごろごろある話」 to mean ありふれた話. ごろごろ here means いくらでもあって、ありふれた存在であるさま。「世間にごろごろしている話」([デジタル大辞泉#5](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E3%81%94%E3%82%8D%E3%81%94%E3%82%8D-505549))

And, the mimetic word ごろごろ and phrases ごろごろする, ごろごろ転がる (roll, roll over) etc. are commonly used to describe 石ころ (stone, rock), so I think people started to use 石ころネタ to mean ごろごろある話, i.e. ありふれた話.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that 石ころネタ means like よくある話(common topic) in this sentence.

You can split this word "石ころ(small stone)" + "ネタ(topic)". No one think about these small stones carefully, but you know these small stones exist everywhere.

If I say this sentence, I choose あるある話 because it is more easier to understand than 石ころネタ.